# Retaining colour compoent when doing OCR using Image magick - tesseract

Tags: imagemagick, tesseract

My initial input is a colour multi column JPG file.  I run image magick on this to create a TIFF file which tesseract 4.0 then performs OCR on to convert the TIFF to a PDF with the text in a searchable form. 
Problem with this is because the TIFF output from Imagemagick is monochrome ( which is has to be for tesseract to extract the text correctly ) the final PDF is monochrome with the text highlightable on it.  What I am trying to figure out is ,  is there a way to retain the colour of the original document when Imagemagick converts it to TIFF?
I am running on Ubuntu 14.0
The goal is to start with a coloured JPG image ( book scan but I don't have control over the scan process so always get a JPG ) which has text on it and convert this to a PDF file which looks the same as the JPG but with the text in a searchable/highlightable format.
My imageMagick command to convert the JPG to tiff is 
convert  -density 300 MyImage.jpg -depth 8 -lat 30x30-5% MyImage.tiff

MyImage.tiff is black and white which works best for Tesseract to to its OCR.

Tesseract command to convert to PDF is
tesseract MyImage.tiff MyImage pdf

But the final PDF will be black and white.  What I would want to have is the text overlayed on a colour version of the original JPG.
Tesseract will only give decent results if using a monochrome input tiff file

Comment: If you need to have a binary (b/w) tiff image for Tesseract, then why do you want to have the original colored lines in the TIFF. It is possible to convert from JPG to TIF in ImageMagick and keep the color lines. Or you can use the b/w image as a mask to color the b/w text with the image color. Can you post an example JPG and explain why you want the colored text? Also what is your ImageMagick version and platform and your exact command line to convert from JPG to TIFF

Comment: Sorry, I still do not know exactly what you want. Do you want the black text to overlay the colored jpg, or do you want the black text to be colored by the colored text from the jpg?  Can you post one of your JPG and TIFF examples and explain which way you want them combined?

Comment: Its probably easier to explain the use case.  Input is a JPG which will be an image with text on it.  Output is some format that retains the appearance of the original JPG but has selectable text.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to make an image or PDF with selectable text.